How do I remove the road line overlap and make it continuous road with different name of roads?


1st Image shows the original road that I want to change like the 2nd image

2nd image: It was done in qgis using advanced symbology. But I want to do it in ArcGIS Pro, is there anything lies in ArcGIS Pro?

Look at the help file here.

You should probably update your question to include the word "symbology" or similar in both the title and the body of the question (I've added it as a tag).  But @Hornbydd is correct - the answer is to use symbol layer drawing in ArcGIS Pro.  If it resolves the problem, add your own answer (below), then accept it as the correct answer.
